# Insert (store/save) FileUpload controller data as binary

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, file-upload, binary-data

I am using fileupload controller, and saving file data as binary in database table, But when I click Save Changes button it does nothing, shows no log, no error, I even gave full permission to IUSR but still have no idea whats going wrong. here is the code.

### ClientSide

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Notifications</h4>
            <hr />

                                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                    <input id="Title" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Notification Titile" type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                    <input id="Discription" runat="server" placeholder="Enter Notification Discription" type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                    <input id="Date" runat="server" placeholder="Notification Date" type="text" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>

            <asp:label runat="server" ID="Msg"></asp:label>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10">
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Text="Save Changes" runat="server"/>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

### CodeBehind

```
        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DbCon obj = new DbCon();
        SqlConnection con = obj.dbconnection();

        string title = NotificationsTitle.Value;
        string discription = NotificationDiscription.Value;
        string date = NotificationDate.Value;

        // Read the file and convert it to Byte Array

        string filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;

        string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

        string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

        string contenttype = String.Empty;

        //Set the contenttype based on File Extension

        switch (ext)
        {

            case ".doc":

                contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";

                break;

            case ".docx":

                contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";

                break;

            case ".xls":

                contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

                break;

            case ".xlsx":

                contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

                break;

            case ".jpg":

                contenttype = "image/jpg";

                break;

            case ".png":

                contenttype = "image/png";

                break;

            case ".gif":

                contenttype = "image/gif";

                break;

            case ".pdf":

                contenttype = "application/pdf";

                break;

        }

        try
        {
            if (contenttype != String.Empty)
            {

                Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;

                BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

                Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);


                con.Open();
                //insert the file into database

                string strQuery = "insert into Notifications(NotificationTitle,NotificationAttachment,NotificationDiscription,NotificationDate,NotificationStatus, NotificationContentType) Values(@title,@data,@dis,@date,@status,@type)";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery, con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title", filename);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data", bytes);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dis", discription);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", "ACTIVE");

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", contenttype);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                NotificationMsg.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully";

            }

            else
            {

                NotificationMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

                NotificationMsg.Text = "File format not recognised." +

                  " Upload Image/Word/PDF/Excel formats";

            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            NotificationMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

            NotificationMsg.Text = "File format not recognised." + ex.ToString();
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would start by removing your try/catch completely. Let the error happen until you figure out what is going on. You are going to insert some breakpoints and step through this.

Comment: I would also caution you against using AddWithValue since you are using pass through queries. It will sometimes get the datatype incorrect. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: @Sean so what are you suggesting? Are you suggesting me to go this way: cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;

Comment: Yes just like that for all your parameters.

Comment: Its not working. I have tried other ways as well but still no success.

Comment: I was not suggesting it would fix the problem. It will avoid more in the future. Did you remove the try/catch? Are you getting an error? Do you know how to set a break point and step through your code? That is what you are going to have to do.

Comment: yeah I tried that as well.
I am getting no error

Comment: Do you know how to set a break point and step through your code?

Comment: Did that as well sir.

Comment: OK well I can't see over your shoulder. What happens? Does it get to the insert statement? Have you run sql profiler to see what is actually being passed to the server? Is there an identity on that table? If so, is it being incremented? Where I am going is you have to figure out where in the process this isn't working. I can't debug this from here, about all I can do is offer some suggestions of where to look.